# For loop CSV - Applying folder permission using Powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to apply bulk network folder permission for each user and folder in a CSV file. My CSV has the headers UserID | Type | Path. Under Path header, I have the path in "\\server\shared\folder1" format.

My issue is that PowerShell 2.0 does not find the path if a use it as a variable in foreach sequence. The code only works if I use the actual path. I don't want to run multiple scripts for every path.

```
Import-Csv C:\BulkFolderPermission.csv | Foreach {
    $path = $_.Path
    $user = $_.UserID
    $type = $_.Type
    $Acl = Get-Acl $path
    $Acl.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(
        $user,
        "$type",     # [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]
        "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", # [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]
        "None",      # [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]
        "Allow"      # [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]
    ))) 
    (Get-Item $path).SetAccessControl($Acl)
}
```

The error that I get is it "cannot find path "\\server\shared\folder1" because it does not exist." But it does exist. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:

The issue is with folder names with special characters such as Ó and é. Can I get help with for a fix?

Comment: Is it `\server\shared\folder1` or `\\server\shared\folder1` (note the double backslash)

Comment: It is the one with the double backslash

Comment: does the account you are using to run the script have permission to see or change that path?

Comment: Yes, I can add and remove permissions manually. I can also read and write access to every folder in each path.

Comment: @Felgie - if you want a person to know that you have replied to their comment, please add the equivalent `@UserName` to your own comment. otherwise, it may go unnoticed. [*grin*]

Comment: @Felgie - thank you for the added info. [*grin*] i can't think of any other reasons, so you may want to add the information to your Original Post.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thank you. I am also wondering as to why it works if the actual path was used instead of pulling it from CSV as variable.

Comment: @Felgie - i don't know ... but i presume there is something not obviously wrong with the data being used. perhaps a leading/trailing space or some non-printing character. you could try piping the CSV import to `Format-Hex` and seeing if there are such. another test would be to check the length of the items to see if they agree with what you _see_.

Comment: Can you try an equality test? Something like `Write-Output ($path == '\\server\shared\folder1')`

Comment: @Soc tried it with folder1 and it works fine, but if the name of the folder is 'folder 1', it can't find the path.

Comment: Are you using single quotes for the path in your csv? If so, remove them.

Comment: @Scepticalist Hi, just updated my post above. The issue is with the special characters such as Ó and é. Is there a way to get around that? Most of the folders were created from Spain.

Comment: Please show the complete error. Do not just paraphrase the message text.

Comment: Is the path correctly displayed in PowerShell or could it be that your `Import-CSV` already has a problem with it?

Comment: Try using the -LiteralPath parameter to access the language characters?